# AngularJs - API controller not being called

Tags: angularjs

My API resources are fine, I can get ALL of a class and populate anything, but for demo purposes here are the API resources as they pertain to EngineMakes:

```
            // EngineMake
            GetEngineMakes: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'EngineMakes' }, isArray: true },
            GetEngineMake: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'EngineMakes' } },
            AddEngineMake: { method: 'POST', params: { controller: 'EngineMakes' } },
            UpdateEngineMake: { method: 'PUT', params: { controller: 'EngineMakes' } },
            DeleteEngineMake: { method: 'DELETE', params: { controller: 'EngineMakes' } },
```

I have a modal form that allows the user to (1) select an engine make and then (2) add a new engine model. I can push the new engine model to scope but it has no association to the respecitive engine make.

Here's my code:

```
// in engine model controller:

$scope.save = function(data) {
    var engineModel = angular.copy($scope.engineModel);
    $http.post('/api/EngineModels/', engineModel)
        .success(function () {
            $rootScope.addEngineModel(engineModel);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
};

// in engine make controller
$rootScope.addEngineModel = function (engineModel) {

the problem --->   $scope.engineMake = API.GetEngineMake({ id: engineModel.FK_EngineMakeId});      

    $scope.engineMake.EngineModels = $scope.engineMake.EngineModels || [];
    $scope.engineMake.EngineModels.push(engineModel);
};
```

1. The new engine model is successfully added to the db and placed into scope.
2. The $rootScope.addEngineModel does get hit, the parameter is correct and the FK_EngineMakeID is correct.**

But, my call to the API is obviously incorrect as I never hit the API controller to find the EngineMake that matches the engine models FK_EngineMakeID **so I can push the new Engine Model to the respective EngineMake.EngineModels**, so when the modal closes and the user selects the engine make, the newly created engine model is part of that collection.

Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

PS: I'd be happy with a simple $http.Get, and forgo the API resource, if someone could show me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it, and then some - note parts I and II, I will explain:**

**Part I:**

```
$rootScope.addEngineModel = function (engineModel) {
    var tmp = $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/EngineMakes/' + engineModel.FK_EngineMakeId }).
              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.engineMake = angular.copy(data);
                  $scope.engineMakes.push($scope.engineMake);
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('fail');
              });

    $scope.engineMake.EngineModels = $scope.engineMake.EngineModels || [];
    $scope.engineMake.EngineModels.push(engineModel);
```

**Part II**

```
    var tmp2 = function () {
        API.UpdateEngineMake({ id: $scope.engineMake.Id }, $scope.engineMake, function (res) {
            if (res.Id > 0) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Part I will update a push to both the EngineMake and EngineModel with the selected EngineMake and newly created EngineModel as being pre-selected once the modal closes with the submit (to add new EngineModel).

But what if the user, for some odd reason, reselects a new EngineMake in the select of the main form (not the modal) and then re-selects the EngineMake he had chosen previously?

**Answer:** He loses scope of the newly created EngineModel UNLESS he refreshes the page.
    Why is that? Because without II, I failed to update the EngineMake's relationship to the EngineModel.

You need Part II to overcome that mishap.

**One final touch:**

Even with step II, there will be 2 identical EngineMakes in the select, one will have the newly created EngineModel, one will not, so what you need to do is something like this (ie filter):

```
     <select id="engineMake" ng-model="engineMake" ng-options="engineMake.Name for engineMake in engineMakes | unique">
      <option value="" selected>Select Engine Manufacturer ..</option>  
     </select>
```

Oy! Me thinks it is time for a raise!